# Python-Streamlit on Heroku, I keep getting h10 error

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

```
2020-07-14T15:23:49.979072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
host=davi-streamlit.herokuapp.com 
request_id=b9ecdd69-aee2-4392-a756-4dad2a070458 fwd="191.181.58.43" 
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

On the `Heroku` website everything works fine on the deploy, but it keeps getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

remove the space between web: and sh

eg:-
web:sh setup.sh && streamlit run xyz.py